# oAuth in python django?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I have created

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/?grant_type=password&username=superadmin&password=superadmin&client_id=aNj1FhsczO3khTZnzNvWL763xwrU1TVzwuOq77Gu&client_secret=xqnq5KGrM6bQz3p3gznGNuj6HGDyEisUjl1fqmjziK1tltO0EZkdnbHMispbRiMTn8FlK1czAoMBCYEn2fmsGpHS3CVMvoFpOQc0ec5Z0BYCHw6XLv61hebdCWdKYeO0
```

my response is::

```
{
    "access_token": "HpA3kWb07goJRXX7cHdIRQhgJUEKe6",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 10000,
    "refresh_token": "3ippzpP42sKs6VdtCvSEMvf0OIBWhq",
    "scope": "read write groups"
}
```

Its working fine only but while running this url again and again the access_token changed with out time expiration how can rectify this. Please help me.

Comment: Access token changing is expected behaviour. Although I don't understand what you meant by time expiration

Comment: My time expiration is 10min right.The time is not finished again run above url the access_token changed.thats my problem i think need to put condition in python ....

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: Yes i installed django-oauth-toolkit==0.8.1

Comment: Again, that is expected behaviour. The token expiration time is for the session. If you request a token, a new token will be generated every time.

Comment: how can do this please tell clearly i need help @TheGeorgeous.

Comment: Please check my answer to this

Answer (score 0):

Expiration time is decided by the server. *It is up to the server to delete the access token after the expiration time.* So when you create a new token, you must store the time, check if the token is valid for every request and if the offset is larger, the server must ask the user to request for a new token.

Comment: if number of access token created means the user can use all tokens right. i need only one access token, after expiration i will get new access token using refresh token.

Comment: please help me i am a new in python django oAuth

Comment: You must delete/disable the old token and replace it with the new token in db whenever a new token is requested